# Check if key value in object A exist in object B

Tags: python

I have 2 Json objects. One is the master json_A that contains all the keys and values and the other json_B contains partial key value from Json_A(master). And I want to check all the keys in json_B exist in json_A(which should) and do some kind of validation based on key pair in Master object.

```
#JSON Format
master_object_A = [
{
  "name": "first_name",
  "type": "string",
  "required": true,
  "format_regex": "",
  "group": "patient"
},
{
  "name": "last_name",
  "type": "string",
  "required": true,
  "format_regex": "",
  "group": "patient"
},
{
  "name": "dob",
  "type": "string",
  "required": false,
  "group": "patient"
},
{
  "name": "phone_no",
  "type": "string",
  "required": false,
  "group": "patient"
 }
]
**************************
json_B = [
{
  "name": "first_name",
  "value": "John Doe"
},
{
  "name": "dob",
  "value": "365-987-9999"
},
```

]

> I want to check if the key value in json_B exist in json_A, then first_name and dob are required or not based on the required status in json_B

This what I have tried but keeps returning false

```
for obj_b in object_B:
      for obj_a in object_A['fields']:
        if obj_a['name'] in obj_b['name']:
          if obj_a['required'] == True and obj_b['name'] == 
             obj_a['name'] and len(obj_b['value']) == 0:
              return true
```

Comment: Please be more precise, provide an exemple of the result you want based on your input example.

Comment: I added what I have tried so far. Please see the update. @CyrillePontvieux

Comment: `len(obj_b['value']) == 0` is never `True` for `json_B`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant `return false`

Comment: your code still says `return true` though

Comment: What you're actually doing here is called schema validation. Consider using a schema validation library ([example](https://github.com/keleshev/schema)) rather than writing this manually. While it might be overkill for this simple example, you may quickly find that it pays dividends.

Answer (score 0):

Using `len(obj_b['value']) == 0` when the key 'value' does not exist will simply throw an exception.

I believe you just need to test if the key `'value' is in obj_b`.
For example

```
for obj_b in object_B:
    for obj_a in object_A:
        if obj_a['name'] == obj_b['name']:
            if obj_a['required'] == True and obj_b['name'] == obj_a['name']:
                if 'value' in obj_b:
                    print (obj_a['name'],obj_b['name'],obj_b['value'])
                    return True
                else:
                    print (obj_a['name'],obj_b['name'])
                    return False
```